answer all these questions based on the uploaded datasets in WEKA apps
PART A.
Load the weather.numeric.arff file into WEKA. This dataset contains medical and health-related information, often used for classification or regression tasks. Use this dataset for item 1-3.
1.Choose the correct statement that describes the dataset.
I.  The number of records is 14, number of input variables is 5, number of class label is 1.

II.  The number of records is 14, number of input variables is 4, number of class label is 2.
III.  The attribute of ‘temperature’ is positively skewed to the right, and ‘humidity’ does not show the data skewness.
IV.  The attributes of ‘temperature’, and ‘humidity’ are positively skewed to the right.

Access the Visualize tab to examine a scatter plot. Determine which of the following statements are FALSE.
I.  There is an unclear correlation between the "humidity" attribute and the "temperature" attribute.
II.  There is a correlation between the "humidity" attribute and the "temperature" attribute.


III.  When the class is 'Yes', the values of 'windy' could be 'true' or 'false'. So, different values of windy could contribute to the class label.
IV.  When the class is 'Yes', the values of 'outlook' are 'sunny' and 'rainy'. So, there is no correlation among any of the attributes.

Apply a suitable filter to find the outliers and extreme values.  Determine which of the following statements are TRUE.
I.  The outlier and extreme values could not be applied because the filter could not be selected.
II.  The steps are Preprocess >> Filter >> Unsupervised >> Attribute >> InterquartileRange >> Apply. The output is no Outliers and Extreme Values in the dataset.


III.  The InterquartileRange can only be used on nominal attributes.
IV.  When the instances consist of Outliers and Extreme Values, the instances are suggested to be deleted / removed from the dataset.

Produce a Simple Linear Regression model using numeric attributes . Use WEKA to generate the formula for the model. Choose the best answers.

I. The formula to estimate temperature is, temperature = 0.49 * temperature + 45.36
II. The formula to estimate humidity is, humidity = 0.49 * temperature + 45.36
III. The formula to estimate temperature is, temperature= 0.2 * humidity + 57.14
IV. The formula to estimate humidity is, humidity = 0.2 * humidity + 57.14
PART B
Load the vote.arff file into WEKA. This dataset contains voting records of U.S. House of Representatives members on various bills, with binary values indicating their "yes" or "no" votes. Use this dataset for item 4-6.

Fix the missing values in the dataset by choosing the right steps. . ONE answer only.
(2 Points)

a. No answer.
b. Select filter>> unsupervised>> attribute>> Replace with Missing Values option and press apply. All attributes will no longer contain any missing values.
c. Select filter>> unsupervised>> attribute>> ReplaceMissingValues option and press apply. All input attributes will no longer contain any missing values.
d. There are no missing values in the dataset.
e. Select filter>> unsupervised>> attribute>> ReplaceMissingValues option and press apply. All attributes will no longer contain any missing values.

After completing Question (4), observe the attribute “duty-free-exports” and “education-spending” in the dataset. Select TRUE statement.
I.  After replacing the missing values, the 'n' label for “duty-free-exports” attribute has increased by 28 records.
II.  After replacing the missing values, the 'n' label for “education-spending” attribute has increased by 31 records.
III.  Both binary attributes have over 50% 'n' responses.
IV.  Both binary attributes have over 50% 'y' responses.

Are there any outliers and extreme values in the dataset? Which one is the right statement?


a. No answer.
b. The steps are Preprocess >> Filter >> Unsupervised >> Instances >> InterquatileRange >> Apply. The filter can not be applied ,due to only nominal attributes in the dataset.
c. The steps are Preprocess >> Filter >> Unsupervised >> Attribute >> Inter quartile Range >> Apply. There are 435 Outliers and Extreme Values in the dataset.
d. The outlier and extreme values could not be applied because there aren't any.
e. The steps are Preprocess >> Filter >> Unsupervised >> Attribute >> Inter quartile Range >> Apply. There are no Outliers and Extreme Values in the dataset.
